# How to append child as last child in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i want to add element to a form in angularjs and do it with out problem. When i post this form created all elements that be added in client side in server side. Now when i want to add new element to form it not add as a last child. How to add element that it be added to form as a last child after submit form?

my Angularjs code is

```
 $scope.addElement = function(){

    var myElements = angular.element(document.querySelector('.list-item'));
    if(myElements.length == 0)
     alert("Not Find");
    else{
        html = angular.element(myElements[0].children[0]).clone();
        myElements.append( html);
     }
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I thought `append` will put the element as the last one?

Comment: @ geckob before submit form its work correctly but after submit form not correctly.

Comment: Then, you should give more code. Maybe plnkr if possible